# Adding a custom stellar token to other exchanges

Tags: exchanges

Are there exchanges other than the Stellar Decentralized Exchange (SDEX) that can list custom Stellar assets? Kind of like how ERC20 tokens can be listed alongside ETH on exchanges.

--

Updated to say "SDEX" instead of StellarTerm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like custom assets listed on SDEX can indeed be found on other exchanges. For example, Mobius (MOBI) is listed on SDEX, Gate.io, GOPAX, Stronghold and OTCBTC. Each exchange would work differently, but I imagine the process would involve sending your Stellar custom asset to a wallet address controlled by the exchange. Traders would then acquire the token on the exchange and transfer it out to their Stellar wallet that can handle custom tokens.

I also found this on a Stellar blog entry: "If an exchange supports Stellar than [sic] it can easily list all other tokens issued on Stellar."

Answer (score 2):

StellarTerm is not an **exchange**. It is a client for the [Stellar distributed exchange (SDEX)](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html) which is build into the Stellar network. Any [Asset](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html) issued in the network can be listed on the SDEX by submitting an offer.

To help you with the terms:

> Cryptocurrency exchanges or digital currency exchanges (DCE) are businesses that allow customers to trade cryptocurrencies or digital currencies for other assets, such as conventional fiat money, or different digital currencies...

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_exchange)

> StellarTerm is an open source client for the Stellar network.

See [StellarTerm](https://stellarterm.com/)

So in case you are looking for alternative clients to StellarTerm, you can use these for example:

- https://stellar.expert
- https://steexp.com/
- ...

If you want to list your assets on an exchange like coinbase.com, bitstamp.net, etc you better get in touch with them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Stellar Decentralized Exchange (SDEX) is built into the Stellar Network, anyone is free to [list tokens](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/custom-assets.html) or [custom assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html#issuing-a-new-asset-type) or [anchor existing tokens](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#anchors-issuing-assets) onto SDEX.

There are many frontend interfaces to SDEX that are developed by the community which allows one to visualize what is happening on SDEX and interact with it. If you are looking for API access you are better off using the [Horizon APIs to deal with SDEX directly](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer).